# How do you declare custom variable inside of make target?

Tags: makefile

How do you define dynamic variables in a makefile target? For example:

```
all:
    VAR := $@
    @echo $(VAR)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realize this is the correct way:

```
all: VAR = $@
all:
    @echo $(VAR)
```

Comment: here are the details:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html